# What tag should be used to make Form layout if we can't use only pure semantic way?

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c, semantic-markup

i know it is pure semantic way

```
<form action="" method="">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Contact Form</legend>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input name="name" id="name" size="20" />
           </fieldset> 
<form>
```

But some time for some design purpose it's not sufficient to get needed style. so my question is other than this purely semantic method

isn't this code is also semantic (after pure semantic method) because form is a group of ordered fields which we fill one by one

```
ol {
  list-style: none; 
  padding-left: 0;
  }


<form action="" method="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Contact Form</legend>

      <ol>
        <li>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input name="name" id="name" size="20" />
       </li> 

       <li>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" size="20" />
       </li>

      <li>
        <label for=" Choices"> Choices (radio)</label>
          <input type="radio" name=" Choice" /> Choice 1
          <input type="radio" name=" Choice" /> Choice 2
          <input type="radio" name=" Choice" /> Choice 3
      </li>

      <li>    
      <label for=" Choices3"> Choices (checkbox)</label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name=" Choice3" /> Choice 1
        <input type="checkbox" name=" Choice3" /> Choice 2
        <input type="checkbox" name=" Choice3" /> Choice 3
     </li>       

     <li>
      <label for="dropdown">Question</label>

        <select id="dropdown">
          <optgroup label="Group of Options">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </li>

      <li>  
      <label for="message">Message</label><br />
        <textarea name="message"rows="12" cols="36"></textarea>
      </li>

      <li><input type="submit" value="send it" /></li>

      </ol>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by semantically correct ? does it validate ? please precise your question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, he's asking whether we personally like his HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If the form fields are meant to be completed in a particular order, then yes, I would say an ordered list is semantically meaningful for separating form elements.

Comment: u r right but can't we say every form which has more than one field is ordered list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra elements to allow more layout styling hooks from CSS, but which have no semantic content in themselves, use `<div>` (or `<span>` for inline). That's what they're there for.

Comment: Well yes, that's the point. It introduces semantics that could be considered misleading. If the form isn't an ordered list of single items (and that's arguable), the semantic content of `<ol>` would be wrong. Adding bad semantic content that isn't really there to a document is worse than omitting semantic content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a definition list, that way your label / input are linked to one another through the for and id, but also through the definition title (label) and definition description (input).

That way you can do some good styling or hide some stuff if needed.